# when i try send sms in sim800l with at+cmgs i have got error

Tags: c, arduino, sim800l

hi it is my code to send "hello world" to my phone number with ardiuno and sim800l but i get Error and when i use "gsm.println("at+cmee=1");" i will get  cms error 305
what is your suggestion to send normal sms with ardiuno and sim800l?

```
    void sends()
  {
  Serial.println("try send sms");
  gsm.println("AT+CSCS=\"GSM\"");
  delay(500);
  gsm.println("at+cmee=0");
 if(gsm.available())
  {
    txt1 = gsm.readString();
    Serial.println(txt1);
  }
  gsm.println("at+cmgf=1");
 delay(500);

 
 if(gsm.available())
  {
    txt1 = gsm.readString();
    Serial.println(txt1);
  }

 
delay(500);
  gsm.print("at+cmgs=\"+98914xxxxxxx\"");
  delay(50);
gsm.println("HELLO WORLD");
delay(50);
gsm.println((char)26);

 // gsm.write(26);
delay(500);
  if(gsm.available())
  {
    txt1 = gsm.readString();
    Serial.println(txt1);
  }
}
```

how can i send sms in ardiuno?

this link suggested by a friend
[+CMS ERROR: 305 when sending SMS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32904626/cms-error-305-when-sending-sms)
but it is vb and i used  gsm.println("AT+CSCS="GSM"");

Comment: i used this in my line gsm.println("AT+CSCS=\"GSM\"");

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
gsm.print("at+cmgs=\"+98914xxxxxxx\"");
```

to

```
gsm.println("at+cmgs=\"+98914xxxxxxx\"");
```

The AT command need to be terminated by a `\r\n` before you inputing your sms message.